# Weed control matting and veg beds

Tags: vegetables, weed-control

I have a couple of raised veg beds. They're currently covered over with some weed control matting, as it's winter and I'm hoping to need to do a little less weeding come spring.

However I'm considering planting some winter varieties of onions - I don't think I've seen many examples of veg beds covered with weed control fabric. Should I remove it before planting, or should I just poke holes in it and sow there?

My major point of concern is that it makes uprooting things with big roots (onions, beetroot) more difficult. And of course, that I've never had much success with the seeds staying where I put them and them wandering over the bed.

Answer (score 4):

Just poke holes in it and plant.  The weed mat is acting also as a mulch to suppress competitors and maintain moisture.

When you want to harvest though, you're probably going to have to cut the mat up to pull your onions out unless you can lift the mat off.